# How to make a POST API with multiple child elements in C#?

Tags: c#, rest, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to create an API call to do a `POST` to a database.

I've generated the models using EF, and have an API that looks like this within the `RecipeController.cs`:

```cs
        [HttpPost] //api/recipe
        public async Task<IActionResult> AddRecipe(RecipeDto newRecipe)
        {
            //default to the recipe being approved 
            sbyte approved = 1;
            //add the recipe itself
            Recipe recipe = _mapper.Map<Recipe>(newRecipe);
            await _dbcontext.Recipes.AddAsync(recipe);

            //for each ingredient in the recipe, add it as an ingredient if it doesn't exist
            //and set the recipe and ingredient to unapproved
            //then add to the recipeIngredients table
            foreach (var ingDto in newRecipe.RecipeIngredients)
            {
                if (ingDto.IngredientId == null)
                {
                    Ingredient ingredient = new Ingredient
                    {
                        Approved = 0,
                        Name = ingDto.IngredientName,
                    };
                    await _dbcontext.AddAsync(ingredient);
                    approved = 0;
                    ingDto.IngredientId =  ingredient.IngredientId;
                }

                var ri =  _mapper.Map<RecipeIngredient>(ingDto);
                await _dbcontext.AddAsync(ri);
            }
            await _dbcontext.SaveChangesAsync();


            return Ok(newRecipe);
        }
```

Essentially, I have to add the `Recipe`, the `Ingredient`, and the `RecipeIngredient` entry.

The last thing that can be added is `RecipeIngredient` (since it's reliant on both `Recipe.RecipeId` and `Ingredient.IngredientId` to be populated)

I also have a field for "Approved" on both `Recipe` and `Ingredient` that needs to be populated (if the `Ingredient` isn't approved, then the `Recipe` should also not be approved) -- this is the part that makes it a bit difficult.

I see three possible approaches to handle this:

1. Do a `for` loop to iterate through the `IngredientsDto` and add any `Ingredients` that don't exist, add the `Recipe`, then do a `for` loop through the `IngredientsDto` AGAIN to populate `RecipeIngredients`.
2. Add the `Recipe`, do a single `for` loop to iterate through `IngredientsDto` to add the `Ingredients` and `RecipeIngredients`, then update the `Recipe` if the `Approved` value should be changed.
3. Like 2, except instead of putting the `Recipe` update within the API just do it in a database trigger.

Which of the three is the best approach?

Is there something I'm fundamentally misunderstanding about the way EF works?

Do I *need* to add `Recipe` before `RecipeIngredient`? Or is EF smart enough to add them in the right order when I save or something?

Please let me know if you need more detail on the models/entities/dbcontext or anything like that.

Comment: What is the clear and objective set of criteria to decide what is best? If you can define such a set of criteria, then why can't you evaluate the various options against the said criteria?

Comment: @Shadow "Clear and best" means optimal best practices programming. I can fake my way through code but I'm trying to learn optimal ways to do things.

Comment: There is no such thing as "optimal best practices programming".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: On testing (since I never got answers),

> Is there something I'm fundamentally misunderstanding about the way EF works?

This was the most relevant answer. My gut instinct was correct - EntityFramework handles adding the `Recipe` and `RecipeIngredient` since there is a list of `RecipeIngredient` within `RecipeDto` already.

I just had to make sure that the `Ingredient` was added correctly, and then EF took care of the rest of it.

```
        //add a new recipe
        [HttpPost] //api/recipe
        public async Task<IActionResult> AddRecipe(RecipeDto newRecipe)
        {
            //default to the recipe being approved 
            sbyte approved = 1;
            //for each ingredient in the recipe, add it as an ingredient if it doesn't exist
            //and set the recipe to unapproved
            foreach (var ingDto in newRecipe.RecipeIngredients)
            {
                if (ingDto.IngredientId == null || ingDto.IngredientId == 0)
                {
                    Ingredient ingredient = new Ingredient
                    {
                        Approved = 0,
                        Name = ingDto.IngredientName,
                    };
                    await _dbcontext.AddAsync(ingredient);
                    approved = 0;
                    ingDto.IngredientId = ingredient.IngredientId;
                }
            }
            await _dbcontext.SaveChangesAsync();
            //add the recipe itself
            Recipe recipe = _mapper.Map<Recipe>(newRecipe);
            recipe.Approved = approved;
            await _dbcontext.Recipes.AddAsync(recipe);
            await _dbcontext.SaveChangesAsync();
            return Ok(newRecipe);
        }
```

Comment: Also I don't know what spots I need `await` in so I put it everywhere which is also probably bad.